# Erro para se conectar com banco sql server 2014 com java e problema com a String de conexão

Tags: java, sql-server

Eu coloquei o jar e fiz o build path .Estou tentando já faz tempo me conectar com o banco da microsoft mas dá este erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falha na conexão TCP/IP com o host localhost, porta 1433. Erro: "Connection refused: connect. Verifique as propriedades da conexão. Verifique se uma instância do SQL Server está sendo executada no host e se está aceitando conexões TCP/IP na porta. Verifique se as conexões TCP na porta não foram bloqueadas por um firewall.".
at br.com.caelum.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:16)
at DAO.ContatoDAO.<init>(ContatoDAO.java:16)
at br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste.TestaConexao.main(TestaConexao.java:22)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falha na conexão      TCP/IP com o host localhost, porta 1433. Erro: "Connection refused: connect.      Verifique as propriedades da conexão. Verifique se uma instância do SQL Server   está sendo executada no host e se está aceitando conexões TCP/IP na porta.  Verifique se as conexões TCP na porta não foram bloqueadas por um firewall.".
at   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at br.com.caelum.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:14)


... 2 more
```

A classe ConnectionFactory

```
package br.com.caelum.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {

private String conexao = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=fj21";

public Connection getConnection(){

    try {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, "sa","");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}
```

}

Mexi nas configurações do servidor do banco deixei o tcp habilitadp.

Comment: Você que instalou esse SQL? Até onde eu saiba o SQL não permite senha em branco para o SA

Comment: @Krismorte dá pra desativar o "password policy", não tem nada demais nisso, fora que o problema dela é com gerar a conexão, o banco nem chega a responder.

Comment: Eu instalei com senha sim @Krismorte tirei pq era meio besta a senha...

Comment: Você desabilitou o firewall? Ou adicionou a porta na 1433 na lista como exceção?

Comment: Não era o firewall, não. Era a String de conexao mesmo...

Comment: Antes de fazer a pergunta eu incluí a porta 1433 sim, lá no tcp/ip...não era isso não.

Comment: Aline, quando você mesma achar a solução da sua pergunta, você pode postar como resposta logo abaixo. Sugiro que edite a pergunta, removendo a resposta, e poste como resposta normalmente, assim fica de acordo com as normas do site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema era a String de conexão do sql que estava incompleta, essa é a forma correta:

```
private String conexao = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=123;databaseName=fj21";
```

Eu consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

```
package factory;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

 public class ConnectionFactory {

  private String conexao = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=123;databaseName=fj21";
  private  String DRIVER ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" ;

  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{

    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER );  
        return DriverManager.getConnection(conexao);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
        throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());  

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Eu vou listar várias causas que podem chegar no seu problema, espero que pelo menos um te sirva.

- Acho que faltou definir o `instanceName` na URL do JDBC. Ele é o nome do serviço do SQL Server. Abrindo o `services.msc`, e procurando pelo serviço do banco você acha um texto entre parêntesis, pra quem instala a versão express do banco normalmente vem como padrão `MSSQLSERVER`.
- Outra coisa é: você só tem o SQL Server 2014 rodando na sua máquina? Se tiver mais de uma, dá conflito na porta 1433 e aí você não vai conseguir conectar de jeito nenhum sem configurar pra deixar habilitado só um por vez.
- Abrir a porta no SQL Server é meio "imbecil" porque você faz isso em dois pontos, então, só pra ter certeza que você realmente abriu a porta fica aqui o passo a passo:

1- No Configuration Manager, vá em "SQL Server Network Configuration", abra o item que seja do teu serviço, clique duplo no item TCP/IP, e passa Enabled pra Yes.[image: Primeira Configuração]

2- Agora na segunda aba, vá até o final e verifique se a porta está definida como 1433.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3- Na parte que leva o nome do driver ODBC(SQL Native Client..., no seu caso acho que é o 12.0), é só seguir os mesmos passos do passo 1, e garantir de novo que a Default Port está 1433 também.

Comment: Pessoal consegui resolver. Coloquei a string de conexao assim:  private String conexao = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=123;databaseName=fj21";

Comment: E mudei a connectionFactory. Vou postar.